# I need to give condition between english keyboard layout and japanese keyboard layout using jquery

Tags: jquery, symbols, cjk, keycode

The following code condition is Japanese keyboard keycode and If I change English keyboard layout it needs to work.

```
$('input,textarea,div#editorId').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if ((e.shiftKey == false && e.keyCode == 220) || (e.shiftKey == false && e.keyCode == 226)) {
    Swal.fire({
      type: "info",
      html: "BackSlash is not allowed",
      confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success"
    })
  } else if ((e.shiftKey == true && e.keyCode == 192) || (e.shiftKey == true && e.keyCode == 50) || (e.shiftKey == true && e.keyCode == 55)) {
    Swal.fire({
      type: "info",
      html: "Double and Single Quotes are not allowed",
      confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success"
    })

  } else if (e.shiftKey == false && e.keyCode == 188) {
    Swal.fire({
      type: "info",
      html: "Comma is not allowed",
      confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success"
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: You should consider using `input` and checking the whole input rather than individual keypresses.   Otherwise the user can just paste in characters that aren't allowed.   If you do this, be sure to preserve the user's carat position.

Comment: Also note: there's no "English layout" - there are different layouts such as Qwerty and Dvorak (though I can't say if they both use the same keyCode) - so check for characters rather than keyCode - keyCode is useful for non-characters such as arrow keys.